# How do I Map a List to another List with a entitymapper?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to map the video_files inside the videos model to video_files inside the videos network model

The error that i'm receiving is a Type Mismatch

Required:List<com.im.xshots.model.videos.Videos.VideoFile>

Found:List<com.im.xshots.data.remote.videos.VideosNetworkEntity.VideoFile>?

Videos Model

```
data class Videos(

    val avg_color: Any? = null,
    val duration: Int? = null,
    val full_res: Any? = null,
    val height: Int? = null,
    val id: Int? = null,
    val image: String? = null,
    val tags: List<Any>? = null,
    val url: String? = null,
    val width: Int? = null,

    val video_files: List<VideoFile>,

    val userId: Int? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val userUrlrl: String? = null,

    val videoId: Int? = null,
    val nr: Int? = null,
    val picture: String? = null,


    ) : Serializable
```

Network model

```
data class VideosNetworkEntity(

    @Json(name = "avg_color")
    val avg_color: Any? = null,

    @Json(name = "duration")
    val duration: Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "full_res")
    val full_res: Any? = null,

    @Json(name = "height")
    val height: Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "image")
    val image: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "tags")
    val tags: List<Any>? = null,

    @Json(name = "url")
    val url: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "user")
    val user: User? = null,

    @Json(name = "video_files")
    val video_files: List<VideoFile>? = null,

    @Json(name = "video_pictures")
    val video_pictures: List<VideoPicture>? = null,

    @Json(name = "width")
    val width: Int? = null,

)
```

EntityMapper

```
class VideosResponseMapper : EntityMapper<VideosNetworkEntity, Videos> {

    override fun fromEntity(entity: VideosNetworkEntity): Videos {
        return Videos(
             avg_color = entity.avg_color,
            duration= entity.duration,
            full_res= entity.full_res,
            height= entity.height,
            id= entity.id,
            image= entity.image,
            tags = entity.tags,
            url = entity.url,
            width = entity.width,
            video_files = entity.video_files //
            ,
            userId= entity.id,
            name= entity.url,
            userUrlrl= entity.url,
            videoId= entity.id,
            nr= entity.id,
            picture= entity.url,
        )
    }

    override fun toEntity(model: Videos): VideosNetworkEntity {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun mapfromEntityList(entityList: List<VideosNetworkEntity>): List<Videos>{
        return entityList.map { fromEntity(it) }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: No worries, thanks

Comment: You try to directly set `video_files = entity.video_files`, but these are also different types. These types needs to be mapped similarly as you do for `VideosNetworkEntity` and `Videos`

Answer (score 0):

I mapped it like I did with VideosNetworkEntity and Videos, if there's a better/efficient way please let me know. Thanks

```
class VideosResponseMapper : EntityMapper<VideosNetworkEntity, Videos> {

    override fun fromEntity(entity: VideosNetworkEntity): Videos {
        return Videos(
            avg_color = entity.avg_color,
            duration = entity.duration,
            full_res = entity.full_res,
            height = entity.height,
            id = entity.id,
            image = entity.image,
            tags = entity.tags,
            url = entity.url,
            width = entity.width,
            video_files = mapFromVideoFileList(entity.video_files!!),
            video_pictures = mapFromVideoPicturesList(entity.video_pictures!!),
            userId = entity.user?.userId,
            name = entity.user?.name,
            userUrlrl = entity.user?.userUrl,

            )
    }

    override fun toEntity(model: Videos): VideosNetworkEntity {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun mapfromEntityList(entityList: List<VideosNetworkEntity>): List<Videos> {
        return entityList.map { fromEntity(it) }
    }

    fun mapFromVideoFile(video: VideosNetworkEntity.VideoFile): Videos.VideoFile {
        return Videos.VideoFile(

            file_type = video.file_type,
            videoFilEhHight = video.videoFileHeight,
            videoFileId = video.videoFileId,
            link = video.link,
            quality = video.quality,
            videoFileWidth = video.videoFileWidth,

            )
    }

    fun mapFromVideoFileList(video: List<VideosNetworkEntity.VideoFile>): List<Videos.VideoFile> {
        return video.map { mapFromVideoFile(it) }
    }


    fun mapFromVideoPictures(video: VideosNetworkEntity.VideoPicture): Videos.VideoPicture {
        return Videos.VideoPicture(

            videoId = video.videoId,
            nr = video.nr,
            picture = video.picture,

            )
    }

    fun mapFromVideoPicturesList(video: List<VideosNetworkEntity.VideoPicture>): List<Videos.VideoPicture> {
        return video.map { mapFromVideoPictures(it) }
    }

}
```